# ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'

Tags: python, python-import

I have a bunch of modules. The modules and their imports are listed below:

```
ast.py:
    import enum
    from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
err.py:
    none
lexer.py:
    from token import TokenTag, Token
parser.py:
    from ast import *
    from err import UndeclaredIdentError, SyntaxError
    from token import TokenTag as Tag
    from type import Type
peep.py:
    from lexer import Lexer
    from parser import Parser
token.py:
    import enum
treewalker.py:
    from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
type.py:
    import enum
    from treewalker import TreeWalker
```

I tried to run peep.py but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peep.py", line 2, in <module>
    from parser import Parser
ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'
```

I don't understand why I got ImportError, I can't find any obvious circular dependencies in the file hierachy above. I did some research, I figured that I should rename the module ast.py to syntaxtree.py because ast.py already exists in Python's standard library. After renaming, it produced the same result. Any form of help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Rename `parser.py` to something else. It's an inbuilt module in python.

Comment: @AjayDabas Is it possible to override the module?

Comment: Simply make an `__init__.py` file in your directory that will tell python to import from the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **parser.py** file and change the code for `from parser import Parser` to `from .parser import Parser`